# Database library

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, indexeddb

I'm currently working on a project that needs to keep some of its functionalities even though there is no internet connection.

I have found that indexeddb is on its way of becoming the new standard however, not all browsers support this yet.

Also android only supports indexeddb in there latest version.

Therefor we also want to use localstorage as a fallback when indexeddb isn't supported.

Is there a library is javascript that detects whether or not indexeddb is supported and uses the appriorate fallback or is that something I will have to manually?

Or does someone has an other solution?

Comment: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/working-with-indexeddb/ might make a good read for you; `if("indexedDB" in window) ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'm currently using is a polyfill for android and iOS so I can use the indexedDB API while it isn't actually supported.
It does this by actually using websql, which is supported on both android and iOS.

websql is supported on android 2+ and iOS 4, if I remember correctly.
See the indexedDBShim for details: https://github.com/axemclion/IndexedDBShim/